PyTorch: CUDA unknown error - GPU not detected (torch.cuda.is_available() returns False)
I'm encountering an error when trying to use PyTorch with GPU acceleration. When I run torch.cuda.is_available(), it returns False.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
/home/ai-132/miniconda3/envs/pranjal2/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py:118: UserWarning: CUDA initialization: CUDA unknown error - this may be due to an incorrectly set up environment, e.g. changing env variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES after program start. Setting the available devices to be zero. (Triggered internally at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1712608853099/work/c10/cuda/CUDAFunctions.cpp:108.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
False

I was expecting it to be True but it returned False.

Have you checked if it works immediately after booting up the system?
I am using Ubuntu and sometimes GPU acceleration stops working on my machine, but restarts solves the issue. It doesn't happen often though so I didn't spend time to investigate what's the root cause.
